# Migrate from Trac to Redmine, and gives the error saying 'gem sqlite3 is not loaded'

Tags: ruby, sqlite, redmine, bitnami

I've been trying to migrate data from Trac 0.11 to Redmine 3.1.1 which both are on the same machine, Windows Server 2012. I installed redmine 3.1.1 with Bitnami, and followed this migration guide: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineMigrate , except sqlite3-ruby because when I installed sqlite3-ruby gem it said that it renamed to sqlite3 so use it instead. I then installed sqlite3 gem as the following command.

```
gem install --local C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sqlite3-1.3.11.gem -- --with-sqlite3-include=D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\sqlite --with-sqlite3-lib=D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\sqlite --with-sqlite3-dir=D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\sqlite
```

The server has a firewall so I downloaded sqlite3 gem and installed it from the local folder.

gem list shows the following,

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.9.6)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

Before executing the rake command, I had to fix the migrate_from_trac.rake as this post suggested: http://www.redmine.org/issues/19173 By the way, the file is located at D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\apps\redmine\htdocs\lib\tasks\migrate_from_trac.rake

Then I ran the following command at D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\apps\redmine\htdocs,

```
bundle exec rake redmine:migrate_from_trac RAILS_ENV="production" --trace

DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
** Invoke redmine:migrate_from_trac (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute redmine:migrate_from_trac

WARNING: a new project will be added to Redmine during this process.
Are you sure you want to continue ? [y/N] y

Trac directory []: D:\TracLight\projects\trac\all
Trac database adapter (sqlite3, mysql2, postgresql) [sqlite3]:
Trac database encoding [UTF-8]:
Target project identifier []: all

This project already exists in your Redmine database.
Are you sure you want to append data to this project ? [Y/n] y

rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/tasks/migrate_from_trac.rake:712:in `block in establish_connection'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/tasks/migrate_from_trac.rake:709:in `each'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/tasks/migrate_from_trac.rake:709:in `establish_connection'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/tasks/migrate_from_trac.rake:374:in `migrate'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/tasks/migrate_from_trac.rake:770:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
D:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.1-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:migrate_from_trac
```

So, I added the following line to the Gemfile which is located at D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\apps\redmine\htdocs

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
```

But it didn't change anything, the above command still gives me the same error. I also tried several bundle commands as the following,

```
bundle install

You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the Gemfile freeze
by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

You have added to the Gemfile:
* sqlite3 (= 1.3.11)
```

However, I can't find any line about sqlite3 on Gemfile.lock. I thought it might be Gemfile.lock file's problem so I then deleted Gemfile.lock and executed bundle install command as the following to recreate it, but it didn't generate Gemfile.lock.

```
build install

You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the Gemfile freeze
by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

You have added to the Gemfile:
* source: rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/
* thin (= 1.6.1)
* eventmachine (= 1.0.3)
* rmagick (= 2.13.4)
* mysql2 (= 0.3.18)
* sqlite3 (= 1.3.11)
* rails (= 4.2.4)
* jquery-rails (~> 3.1.3)
* coderay (~> 1.1.0)
* builder (>= 3.0.4)
* request_store (= 1.0.5)
* mime-types
* protected_attributes
* actionpack-action_caching
* actionpack-xml_parser
* loofah (~> 2.0)
* tzinfo-data
* rbpdf (~> 1.18.6)
* net-ldap (~> 0.3.1)
* ruby-openid (~> 2.3.0)
* rack-openid
* redcarpet (~> 3.3.2)
* activerecord-jdbc-adapter (~> 1.3.2)
* activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
* rdoc (>= 2.4.2)
* yard
* minitest
* rails-dom-testing
* mocha
* simplecov (~> 0.9.1)
* capybara
* selenium-webdriver
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that all the things were done on Bitnami Redmine Stack Environment by clicking use_redmine.bat at D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install sqlite3 gem to under the D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\apps\redmine\htdocs\vendor\bundle\ruby\2.0.0\gems for bundler. To do so, I ran the following command.

```
bundle exec gem install --local C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sqlite3-1.3.11.gem -- --with-sqlite3-include=D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\sqlite --with-sqlite3-lib=D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\sqlite --with-sqlite3-dir=D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\sqlite
```

Then, I could see that the sqlite3 folder at D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\apps\redmine\htdocs\vendor\bundle\ruby\2.0.0\gems\sqlite3-1.3.11

After that, I needed to add the line "sqlite3 (1.3.11)" at the end of GEM section of Gemfile.lock at D:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.1-1\apps\redmine\htdocs. Then "bundle show" starts showing me "sqlite3 (1.3.11)" on the list.

Although I could successfully run the migrate_from_trac task, other error happens during migrating wiki. But that's another story.